# sharepoint api resultrs null

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint

I used this same code; on an identical list and it worked.  But when I drill to results; I will see it in the console (line item) then it shows that same line item as an error stating results are null or not defined.  Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

```
    function load_nav(){
    var lib='Links';
    var fld='ID,Title,Link,Category,Active';
    var exp='';
    var fil='Active eq 1';
    var ord='ID asc';
    var url='/site/go/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(\''+lib+'\')/Items?$select='+fld+'&expand='+exp+'&$filter='+fil+'&$orderby='+ord;
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:url,
        contentType:'application/json;odata=verbose',
        headers:{'accept':'application/json;odata=verbose'},
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data.d.results);
            var dat=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)).d.results;
            var lnk='',ttl='',a='',b='',c='';
            $.each(dat,function(idx,itm){
                    lnk='<li class="bullet2"><a href='+itm.Link+'>'+itm.Title+'</a></li>';
                    console.log(itm.Category.results);
                    if(itm.Category.results==='Resources'){a+=lnk;}
            });
            $('#nav ul').append(a);


        },
        error:function(){
            console.log('Error loading navigation');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you get the result if you browser the rest api endpoint in browser directly?

Comment: Yes, its weird as I get the results in a console.log, reading line 51.  Then immediately after there is an error saying results null on line 51!?  Pointing to if (itm.Category.results... results being the error....

Comment: Try to use developer tool to monitor the runtime values( not just by console.log), provide screenshots so others could try to check.